# Problem with Solidity compiler

Tags: compiler

recently I started doing solidity tutorial. Everything was going okay on remix but when i switched to VS Code I got compiler error

[image]

I changed it to:

[image]

but it doesnt solve the question why 0.8.8 compiler version doesn't work.

Answer (score 2):

are you using a framework like hardhat or similar. if so, it's not using the compiler set in vscode, so you can ignore it. If, like me, you find it too annoying, lookup the solidity configuration settings in vscode settings. you'll have to do a little research on those settings to set them properly but you can fake the entry and it makes the errors go away.

like this. (it's not right, but stops the errors)
[image]